# Change google maps API route planner language

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a routeplanner on my website, and changed the language of the script to Dutch, like this:

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false;language=nl"
```

The map's language is Dutch now, but the language of the routeplanner isn't:

```
1.  Head southeast on Aalbershof    
20 m
2.  Turn left to stay on Aalbershof 
90 m
3.  Turn right to stay on Aalbershof    
38 m
4.  At the roundabout, take the 1st exit onto Oosterlandenweg   
1.4 km
5.  Turn left onto Zwolseweg

etc.
```

How do I change the language of the routeplanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization you use the API correctly. Could it be, that you need to divide your parameters with **&** instead of **;**?

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=nl"
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks alot! I searched on the internet how to change the language, but they all said I had to use a ':' instead of a '&', weird.